# Is there a way to force usage of named parameters instead of your standard function_name(var, var)?

Tags: ruby, syntax, semantics

I really like named parameters, as they greatly help with the readability of my code.

Ruby uses pseudo-named parameters with hashes, and I've implemented a few methods using that technique, but adding these three lines to every method with parameters would get cumbersome:

```
def something_does_something_with(parameters = {})
  default_params = {:some => option, :another => something}
  parameters = default_params.merge(parameters)
  ...
end
```

or the method header could be like this:

```
def something_does_something_with(parameters = {:some => option, :another => something})
```

but then I think if I supply any parameters at all, it overrides the entire default hash.

When I worked with Objective-C, named-variables were my favorite thing in the programming universe.

Is there a way to modify the default way Ruby looks at method headers such that named-parameterss are required, or at least easier?

Comment: One way you can accomplish something similar to this is having a method like you have above, where it takes a hash as an argument, and then use the hash keys sort of like named parameters.  If you had the method above, your call to the method could look like this: `something_does_something_with(:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2')` (etc).  It's not quite the same but it's very common practice in Ruby and essentially accomplishes the same goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can not use second example because it will work only in case when you're passing a full set of parameters.

In reference to your first example you could make it short like this:

```
def something_does_something_with(parameters = {})
  parameters = {:some=>option,:another=>something}.merge(parameters)
  ...
end
```

And finally, the named parameters is planning to implement in the next version of Ruby - Ruby 2.0

Comment: Ruby 2.0 is going to be the best ruby. o.o